# How do I make my python discord bot say the same message every 0.10 seconds

Tags: python, discord

There has been a competition in my discord server to say the most amount of messages in a 24 hour span. I didn't want to do it manually so I decided to create a bot. The bot can send a message when I say something now but I want to make it repeat.

```
**import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("test"):
        await message.channel.send("example")
client.run('TOKEN')**
```

Comment: Haha well your gonna win!

Comment: You can import time, put the message part into a while loop at the end of the loop put a `time.sleep(amount_time)` and run it should work. "Send  a message"...." wait".... "Send a message". Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    message.channel.send("message")
    sleep(.1) # time.sleep takes time in seconds
```

Comment: It says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/My Computer/Desktop/nwor/nworl.py", line 7, in <module>
    message.channel.send("message")
NameError: name 'message' is not defined"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.